# How to set family keys with pgfkeys and a macro?

Tags: latex, pgf

I want to set 2 keys of a pgfkeys-family using a macro :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
    /keys/.is family,
    /keys/.cd,
    test 1/.store in=\testone,
    test 1=unset,
    test 2/.store in=\testtwo,
    test 2=unset,
}

\pgfkeys{/store/.code={\pgfkeys{/keys/.cd,#1}}}
\def\mykey{test 1=ONE,test 2=TWO}
\pgfkeys{/store=\mykey}
t1 : \testone,   
t2 : \testtwo.
\end{document}
```

I hope to get :

```
t1 : ONE, t2 : TWO.
```

And I get :

```
t1 : unset, t2 : unset
```

And an error message :

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/keys/test 1=ONE,test 2=TWO'
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

What did i miss ?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do what you want is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfkeys{
    /keys/.is family,
    /keys,
    test 1/.store in=\testone,
    test 1/.initial=unset,
    test 2/.store in=\testtwo,
    test 2/.initial=unset,
}
\newcommand\setkeys[1]{\pgfkeys{/keys,#1}}

\begin{document}
  \setkeys{test 1=ONE,test 2=TWO}
  t1 : \testone,
  t2 : \testtwo.
\end{document}
```

Points to note:

- use the `.initial` handler to set the initial value of the key
- you do not need the `.cd` handler for a family
- I have defined the macro `\setkeys` to set the keys from a comma separated list
- if you want to set the keys using a macro that is defined like `\def\mykey{test 1=ONE,test 2=TWO}` you run into some mildly painful expansion problems. One way around this is to use `\edef\Addkey{\noexpand\pgfkeys{/keys, \mykey}}\Addkey`
- rather than using `.store in` you can let `\pgfkeys` store the values of the keys and use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/keys/test 1}` etc to print their values. I usually define a macro like `\newcommand\Keys{\pgfkeysvalueof{/keys/#1}}` to do this, which you would use as `\Keys{test 1}`.

Btw, you are better off posting TeX questions on tex.stackexchange.com.